# How can I pass @<text> for an extension method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How can I pass `@<text></text>` for an extension method?

I created this extension class:

```
public class CustomPanel
{
    public CustomPanel()
    {
        this.Fields = new List<string>();
    }

    private List<string> Fields { get; set; }

    public void AddField(string format)
    {
        this.Fields.Add(format);
    }

    public MvcHtmlString GetHtml()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var field in this.Fields)
            sb.AppendFormat("{0} <br>", field);

        return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
}

public static class PanelExtension
{
    public static CustomPanel CreatePanel(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        return new CustomPanel();
    }
}
```

When I call the method:

```
@{
    var panel = @Html.CreatePanel();
}

panel.AddField(@<text>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BarCode)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.BarCode)
</text>)
```

Ocurre the following error:

> "<" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers,
>   keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing `panel.AddField(@<text> ...` to `panel.AddField(@(text)`?

Comment: But, how can I utilize the @Html. on @(text)?

Comment: why cant you do something simple like this - `@{
    var labelForHtml =   Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nature);
    var textForHtml = Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nature);
    var str = string.Format("{0}{1}", labelForHtml, textForHtml);    
}` and then use str to pass it to your `AddField()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a better idea.

I'm passing the expression to method, and inside I created the html code.

```
public class CustomField
{
    public CustomField(MvcHtmlString label, MvcHtmlString input)
    {
        this.Label = label;
        this.Input = input;
    }

    public MvcHtmlString Label { get; private set; }
    public MvcHtmlString Input { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}", this.Label, this.Input);
    }
}

public class CustomPanel<TModel>
{
    public CustomPanel(HtmlHelper<TModel> html)
    {
        if (html == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("html");

        this.Html = html;
        this.Fields = new List<CustomField>();
    }

    private HtmlHelper<TModel> Html { get; set; }
    private List<CustomField> Fields { get; set; }

    public void AddField<TValue>(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        this.Fields.Add(new CustomField(this.Html.LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(expression), this.Html.TextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(expression)));
    }

    public MvcHtmlString GetHtml()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var field in this.Fields)
            sb.AppendFormat("{0} <br>", field);

        return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
}

public static class PanelExtension
{
    public static CustomPanel<TModel> CreatePanel<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html)
    {
        return new CustomPanel<TModel>(html);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    var panel = @Html.CreatePanel();
    panel.AddField(model => model.Reference);
    panel.AddField(model => model.Barcode);
}

@panel.GetHtml()
```